# Iterate over timeline partitions, fastest pull of days in each

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Using 2.3.1 of Neo4j,

Have a timeline of nodes similar to what [Mark Needham](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2014/04/19/neo4j-cypher-creating-a-time-tree-down-to-the-day/) blogged about.  I would like to capture the days between the **from** and **to** for each partition.  Grabbing the length of the path (as shown in the query below) is fast.  However, if I put something like:

```
match (from)-[:NEXT*..]->(day:Day)-[:NEXT*0..]->(to)
return partition.name, count(day)
```

then the query times out.  Realize that an infinite [:NEXT*0..] range isn't terribly smart but the span between **from** and **to** could be a couple weeks, or a month or a big as a year (i.e. random).  So what I need is the **days** (i.e. the nodes) in the path.  Also, a side-question is if iterating of a literal map (i.e. the partitions) in this fashion is efficient?

(fast path query)

```
with [
 {
  name: "p1",
  from: {year: 2014, month: 5, day: 1},
  to: {year: 2014, month: 5, day: 18}
 },
 {
  name: "m2",
  from: {year: 2014, month: 6, day: 1},
  to: {year: 2014, month: 6, day: 11}
 },
 {
  name: "m3",
  from: {year: 2015, month: 1, day: 1},
  to: {year: 2015, month: 1, day: 21}
 }
] as partitions
unwind(partitions) as partition
match (:Year {id: partition.from.year})
  <-[:IN_YEAR]-(:Month {month: partition.from.month})
  <-[:IN_MONTH]-(from:Day {day: partition.from.day})
with partition, from
match (:Year {id: partition.to.year})
  <-[:IN_YEAR]-(:Month {month: partition.to.month})
  <-[:IN_MONTH]-(to:Day {day: partition.to.day})
with partition, from, to
match p=(from)-[:NEXT*0..]->(to)
return partition.name, p
```

**Update 2** Using unwind again on the path I can get at the days:

```
with partition, nodes(p) as links
unwind links as days
```

then keep matching off **days**.  But is this the most efficient way to partition up days (**note**: need to allow for overlapping partitions) so I can key off them (i.e. match) to get at other parts of the graph?

Comment: Running **profile** the largest number of DB hits comes from the variable length expansion of the path (i.e. **p**) over the **NEXT** relationships.  And that is the problem, the length of the path is determined by the date range for each partition.

Answer (score 1):

[EDITED]

Since all the nodes between `from` and `to` are `Day` nodes, then you can get the nodes in each path of interest this way:

```
...
MATCH p=(from)-[:NEXT*0..]->(to)
RETURN partition.name, NODES(p) AS nodes;
```

Comment: thanks for the cypher but really need to get at the nodes in the path not the count.  Will update my question to reflex that.

Comment: also the NEXT one-way relation is connects just days.